# Docusign Custom Button & Salesforce Contact Roles

Tags: docusignapi

I've been stuck on the code for my custom button for a few weeks now with no luck from Docusign support.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm creating a Custom Button on my Opportunity to pull in the Contacts listed under "Contact Roles" on the opportunity.  This portion seems to be working perfectly and pulling the contacts correctly.

However, I can't seem to pull in the Opportunity Owner email address with the correct role.  The Opportunity Owner keeps pulling in as a Signer whereas they should be a Carbon Copy.

A couple of notes: Proposal CC is my Salesforce Role, I'm not pulling in a template, I'm working with SF Professional Edition with an API

[In this image - the Top Row is the Opportunity Owner and the following rows are Contact Roles which are correct:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xf8u.png)

[Here are Contact Roles within Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCVmo.png)

Here's the Code I'm using:

{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [SourceID=Opportunity.Id])}
&DSEID=0&OCO=&CCRM=Signer+1~Signer+1;Proposal+CC~Carbon+Copy;Decision+Maker~Signer+3;Evaluator~Carbon+Copy&CCTM=Signer+1~Signer;Proposal+CC~Carbon+Copy;Decision+Maker~Signer+3;Evaluator~Carbon+Copy&CRL=Email~{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail};FirstName~{!Opportunity.OwnerFirstName};LastName~{!Opportunity.OwnerLastName};Role~Carbon+Copy

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Please properly format your code using the brackets to the left of the image icon in the text editor. You can use the ` symbol before and after single-line code or the icon to the right of the image icon in the text editor for functional code (HTML, CSS, and JS).

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Create a new button from scratch and adding a CRL pulling the information from the Opportunity Owner. Custom URL button code below.

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [ 
SourceID = Opportunity.Id, 
CCRM = 'Primary Guarantor~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2', 
CCTM = ' Primary Guarantor~Signer;Signer 2~Carbon copy;AE~Receives a Copy', 
CRL = 'Email~' + Opportunity.OwnerEmail + ';FirstName~' + Opportunity.OwnerFirstName 
+ ';LastName~' + Opportunity.OwnerLastName + ';Role~TestRole;RoutingOrder~1', 
OCO = 'Preview', 
LA = '1' 
] 
)}
```